# How does pH level change the concentration of dissolved oxygen (DO) in sea water?

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry, environmental-chemistry

I am planning to investigate the relationship between $\mathrm{pH}$ and dissolved oxygen.

I would like to have a reason without taking in account the plants, animals and decomposer roles.

I want to know if $\mathrm{pH}$ affects the concentration of dissolved oxygen. For example:

If I added $\ce{HCl}$ to water, would the concentration of DO change?
In same way, if I add $\ce{NaOH}$, would the concentration of DO change?

Comment: In short: no, it does not, at least until you reach the truly extreme concentrations.

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium of dissolved-to-gas-phase oxygen is not affected by the aqueous hydronium ion concentration ($\ce{H3O+}$), and thus the pH of water does not affect dissolved oxygen concetrations of sea water.